# How to connect to a server running on docker host from a container in rootless mode?

Tags: linux, docker, rootless

My docker container runs an application which needs to connect to a websocket server running on the host.

Docker is in rootless mode to launch the docker service on a non-sudoer user account.

I did not find any way to ping the host from the container...

Any suggestion ?

Host OS: ubuntu 20.04
Container OS: ubuntu 20.04
docker version: 24.0.5

I read https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/

Adding -p PORT_ON_HOST:PORT_IN_CONTAINER does not work because the PORT_ON_HOST is already used by the websocket server.

For now I use this work around: docker service is launched as root at boot and the non-sudoer user can run containers on this docker service. But I really would like to run a rootless docker daemon for security reasons.

Comment: It's unusual for containers to connect out to host.  Is the websocket server also running in a container?  If it is you could manage this using the docker virtual network...

Comment: No the websocket server si running on the host as a classic application on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Are you able to use host network then perhaps?

Comment: No host network is not available in rootless mode: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#known-limitations

Comment: In that case I believe you will need either create a tunnel or connect to the websocket server using the external interface.